# Sum and product of numerator of rational number doubt

Tags: summation, rational-numbers, products

Given the sum rule:
$$
\frac{n}{m}+\frac{r}{s}=\frac{n \cdot s+m \cdot r}{m \cdot s}
$$
the product rule:
$$
\frac{n}{m} \cdot \frac{r}{s}=\frac{n \cdot r}{m \cdot s}
$$
and the quotient rule:
$$
\frac{\frac{n}{m}}{\frac{r}{s}}=\frac{n}{m} \cdot \frac{s}{r}
$$
why:
$$
\frac{m+\frac{r}{s}}{n} = \frac{ms+r}{ns}
$$
it is not:
$$
\frac{m+\frac{r}{s}}{n} = \frac{\frac{ms+r}{s}}{n} = \frac{n(ms+r)}{s}
$$

Comment: Your last step is wrong : $\frac{\frac{ms+r}{s}}{n} = \frac{ms+r}{s} \cdot \frac{1}{n}$.

Comment: Yes, I know this is wrong, but I don't understand why it is so given the quotient rule

Comment: Following the quotient rule I'd write $\frac{\frac{ms+r}{s}}{n} =\frac{ms+r}{s} \cdot \frac{n}{1}$

Comment: following the quotient rule you will write reciprocal of n in multiplication

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that $n = \frac{n}{1}$ and thus, $$\frac{\frac{ms+r}{s}}{n} = \frac{\frac{ms+r}{s}}{\frac{n}{1}} = \frac{ms+r}{s} \cdot \frac{1}{n} = \frac{ms + r}{ns}.$$

Answer (score 2):

See when you are confused in such cases use brackets

$\frac{m+\frac{r}{s}}{n} =\frac{(m+\frac{r}{s})}{n}= \frac{(\frac{ms+r}{s})}{n} = \frac{(ms+r)}{ns}$